# How can I enable Python debugging in CentOS 7 non-GUI?

Tags: python, centos

I have a python flask code deploy on VPS with centos 7 (Non GUI). and my goals is to enable debugging when error happens. is it possible to install PyCharm in centos 7 no GUI? or is there any way to setup debugging so i can enable debug features?

I wanna find features for enable debbuging python in centos 7 non GUI.